# How can I determine if a date is between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I need know if a `$paymentDate` (31/12/2010) is valid between `$contractDateBegin`(01/01/2001) and `$contractDateEnd`(01/01/2012)

***dd/mm/yyyy FORMAT !***

Comment: What is the format of each of the variables? Is it a timestamp?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What format are the dates in?

Comment: And, what date format is expected in $contractDateBegin, $contractDateEnd and $paymentDate ?

Comment: unfortunately the solution was: http://pastebin.com/ZPckEWgc

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3:

```
$paymentDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2010');
$contractDateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/2001');
$contractDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/2012');

if ($paymentDate >= $contractDateBegin && $paymentDate <= $contractDateEnd)
{
  echo "is between\n";
}
```

You may need to adjust the use of `<=` to `<` depending on whether or not the dates are exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

if they are formatted as YYYYMMDD you can check if `$paymentDate > $contractDateBegin and $paymentDate < $contractDateEnd`

This works with any numeric format that has the larger formats first.  If you have american dates for example MM/DD/YYYY, it doesn't work.

Comment: Works with UNIX timestamps and various other formats as well.

Comment: @Wesley: tried to make it more clear that this works for most time formats :)

Comment: Basically any format that can be represented by a number where a later date is always greater than an earlier one. Terribly simple.

Comment: American dates are typically MM/DD/YYYY, but you are correct regardless... such a check would fail with them.

Comment: Works with date('Y-m-d') or YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 3):

```
$test = strtotime($paymentDate);
if ($test >= strtotime($contractDateBegin) && $test <= strtotime($contractDateEnd))
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if either time is formatted as UNIX timestamp. `strtotime()` will return FALSE. After OP's edit it looks like this is what he wants.

Comment: `strtotime` won't work because it assumes anything with `/` is in m/d/Y format. The dates would need to have dashes in order for `strtotime` to work.